# Error when running `feathers generate authentication` for `RethinkDB`

Tags: macos, rethinkdb, feathersjs, feather

I’m having issues when running `feathers generate authentication` with selecting `rethinkdb` as database.

*Environment:*

- Mac OS X Sierra
- feathers 2.2.3
- npm 5.1.0
- rethinkdb 2.3.5

*Steps to reproduce:*

1. I have up and running https://github.com/tenzan/feathers-chat.git
2. `feathers generate authentication`
3. Select `Username + Password (Local)`
4. What is the name of the user (entity) service? (users) <-- Enter
5. What kind of service is it? (Use arrow keys) ❯ RethinkDB <-- Enter

*Output:*

```
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not object
    at Url.parse (url.js:102:11)
    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:96:5)
    at ConnectionGenerator._getConfiguration (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/feathers-cli/node_modules/generator-feathers/generators/connection/index.js:46:24)
    at ConnectionGenerator._writeConfiguration (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/feathers-cli/node_modules/generator-feathers/generators/connection/index.js:103:32)
    at ConnectionGenerator.writing (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/feathers-cli/node_modules/generator-feathers/generators/connection/index.js:297:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/feathers-cli/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:417:23)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/feathers-cli/node_modules/run-async/index.js:25:25
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/feathers-cli/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:19
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/feathers-cli/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:418:9
```

I had same errors on different Mac PCs with same environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with `generator-feathers`

Remove the `rethinkdb` object from `config/default`

will see if I can fix the main problem

Edit: Fixed